# Can't apply styling through Javascript to a HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm really new to Javascript, I am building a webpage and wanted the navbar to change size when the user scrolls down. This was only possible by using Javascript.

I referenced the .js file in my HTML file and added an onscroll event to the navbar with a function that I defined in the Javascript file. Thing is, the styling doesn't apply. I already checked if the function is actually being called by adding a console.log();. I found out the function is being called but the styling won't apply for some reason.

Here is my HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Remote Homework') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Stylesheet from initial build, located in public folder -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('style.css') }}" type="text/css">


</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav id="navbar" onscroll="navbarSizing()" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm sticky-top">
            <!-- Use container-fluid to arrange navbar items from edge to edge -->
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('home') }}#content1">
                    <img src="{{ asset('images/better_logo.png') }}" alt="Logo" style="width:105px;">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('home') }}#content1">{{ __('Home') }}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('home') }}#content2">{{ __('Info') }}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('home') }}#content3">{{ __('Contact') }}</a>
                        </li>
                        @auth()




                        @endauth
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        <!-- only gets called when user is logged in -->
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <!-- put the route for the 'public' questions here-->
                                <a href="{{ route('questions.feed') }}" class="nav-link">Question Feed</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('questions.overview') }}">{{ __('My questions') }}</a>
                                    <!--<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('pages.dashboard') }}">{{ __('Dashboard') }}</a>-->
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('questions.create') }}">{{ __('Ask a question') }}</a>

                                    <hr class="dropdownmenu-hr">

                                    <a class="dropdown-item"
                                       href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"
                                    >
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>



                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            <!-- main content of the page -->
            @yield('content')
        </main>
        <!-- the footer of the page -->
        @include('pages.footer')
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JS file

```
function navbarSizing() {
    let element = document.getElementById("navbar");

    element.style.color = "blue";
    console.log("This works!");
}
```

Can somebody see the problem? I've been stuck with this issue for hours. Thanks in advance!

Comment: um, is the navbar actually scollable?

Comment: Jumping off what @epascarello said, you aren't actually scrolling the navbar. You want to respond to the page being scrolled, not the navbar. Try moving the onscroll event to your App div or body tag, depending on your styles

Comment: I see your point. I already tried changing the onscroll event to an onclick event to check if it would make a difference. When I checked the console, the debug message was in fact being displayed but my styling didn't apply. I now tried applying the onscroll event to the parent <div> and for some reason it doesn't work when i scroll. Yet again, i'm very unfamilliar with Javascript.

Comment: I now added the onscroll event to the <body> tag. The function seems to be called properly because my debug message is being displayed in the console. But the styling still doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is that since `nav` does not have a scrollbar, so it will not get event on scrolling. Try adding event handler on `body` element.

Second, the style `color` that you are applying is not visible in nav element, because it applies on text color, and `nav` element does not have any text, it contains other elements. As you said that you want to change size, try, for example:

```
element.style.height = "500px";
```

Comment: This did the trick. Such an obvious solution! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change css of the element, use can use jQuery. Here is the simple example to change the css using jQuery. I hope it helps to answer you or give you an idea.

```
function navbarSizing() {
    let element = $("#navbar").find('ul');
    element.css('background-color', 'red');
    console.log("This works!");
}
```

In this example, it is changing the background color. So first of all you have to find the correct element to apply the css. So, if you want to change text color of li, so first you need to find the li children of the ul element.

For more reference, you can read doc from https://api.jquery.com/. Also, include jQuery in your html as